# Notification in Tizen

Tags: c, linux, tizen, tizen-native-app

How can i get the list of notifications occurring on the tizen device in a native c code? I am writing a native c code which will run on the tizen device, and the list of notifications need to be printed continuously in my native application

Comment: all kind of notifications coming in the notification bar like "new msg received", "1 missed call", "Avast is scanning your device" etc

Comment: I don't think that can be done easily in c. But in c++ you have to add various listener interfaces to achieve the task.

Comment: hi, I am interested in doing the same thing. How can I do it in C/C++? There are no api's I could find to achieve this.

Comment: You want the list of notifications posted by any app in the Tizen mobile? or just list of notifications posted by your own app?

Answer (score 1):

There is a getAll() API if you are writing a webapp.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/how-use-tizen-notification-api

You can refer to the webruntime code to see what it is doing.